# Latex \newcommand argument

Tags: arguments, latex, footnotes

I have a Latex text for which I want to write a very basic class to render. basically all of the text's commands need defining. I am doing well so far until I hit this:

`\swordfootnote{1}{}{Philemon 1:23}{crossReference}{}{See \swordxref{Col.1.7}{Col. 1:7}}`

Basically this is a fancy footnote which I simply, at this moment at least, want to render as a footnote. It has 6 arguments, but I really only need the last one, which is the footnote text.

I have done the following:

`\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\swordxref}[2]{\hyperref{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\swordfootnote}[6]{\footnote{#6}}`

I am getting on compiling messages that there is a superfluous }.

`! Argument of \@finalstrut has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9 ...ver. 9}; See \swordxref{Eph.3.1}{Eph. 3:1}}`

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `\hyperref` is incorrect. The "two-argument" version of `\hyperref` uses the interface

```
\hyperref[<label>]{<text>}
```

with square brackets for the first argument.

Here's a minimal example showing the usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=20\baselineskip]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\swordxref}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\swordfootnote}[6]{\footnote{#6}}
\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{sec:section}

See~\swordxref{sec:section}{this section} or a footnote\swordfootnote{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{See~\swordxref{sec:section}{this section}.}.

\end{document}
```